# Maya all imports are with an angle

Tags: 3d, maya

I've got this weird problem with all improts and objects that I create in Maya 2016...the thing is that they appear with the 90-degree angle.

What's wrong with that and how can I fix it?

[The screenshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC0Yv.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Comment: You should ask in some 3d forums like cgtalk or something.. voting to close

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question and should be asked in a proper forum. That being said: Check that the file you're importing was authored in the same coordinate system as the one you're currently using.

`Window -> Settings/Preferences --> Preferences`, look under `Settings` for `World Coordinate System`... Your up axis is most likely set to Z, and the file you're importing was probably authored in a Y up coord system.